# Functions are not visible from my DLL

Tags: c++, dllexport

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Creating C++ Win32 project.

I define my functions like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int  __stdcall function1(par1,par2,..)
```

DLL compiled successfully. Why I don't see the function in DLL Export Viewer and similar tools (dumpbin and so on). What else should I add?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code and putting it in a blank Win32 DLL project does indeed produce an exported function in the DLL.

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int  __stdcall function1(int p)
{
    return p;
}
```

So I'm not sure what it is you did above and beyond the "normal"

Comment: Can it be because #include "stdafx.h" is not added before these functions but added below in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution i.e. my fault. There was a code in the same cpp:

```
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    //----
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    //----
    return(TRUE);
}
```

The same as in dllmain.cpp. And that is why including "stdafx.h" before the above code called error of multiple definitions. Once I removed the code above I put include "stdafx.h" in the top of the file, compiled and my functions became "visible".